# Kubernetes cert-manager challenges hanging

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

The challenges created by cert-manager for creating new certificates are hanging.
No events, no state.

`kubectl describe clusterissuers letsencrypt-prod`

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2021-05-14T23:01:20Z'
  generation: 1
  managedFields:
    - apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:spec':
          'f:acme':
            'f:email': {}
            'f:privateKeySecretRef':
              'f:name': {}
            'f:server': {}
            'f:solvers': {}
      manager: Terraform
      operation: Apply
      time: '2021-05-14T23:01:20Z'
    - apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:status':
          .: {}
          'f:acme':
            .: {}
            'f:lastRegisteredEmail': {}
            'f:uri': {}
          'f:conditions': {}
      manager: controller
      operation: Update
      time: '2021-05-14T23:01:22Z'
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  resourceVersion: '8694175494'
  uid: 9e608463-7f3f-466b-a07f-4d5b5c1fd6fd
spec:
  acme:
    email: contact@kmp.agency
    preferredChain: ''
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    server: 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory'
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
status:
  acme:
    lastRegisteredEmail: contact@kmp.agency
    uri: 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/123552627'
  conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: '2021-05-14T23:01:22Z'
      message: The ACME account was registered with the ACME server
      observedGeneration: 1
      reason: ACMEAccountRegistered
      status: 'True'
      type: Ready
```

`kubectl -n citizen-capital describe citizen-capital-preprod-tls-7dnxx-3938188414-701554649`

```yaml
Name:         citizen-capital-preprod-tls-7dnxx-3938188414-701554649
Namespace:    citizen-capital
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Challenge
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-11-24T14:39:58Z
  Finalizers:
    finalizer.acme.cert-manager.io
  Generation:  1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:finalizers:
          .:
          v:"finalizer.acme.cert-manager.io":
        f:ownerReferences:
          .:
          k:{"uid":"ee84badd-8772-4714-bd39-f869da6badf5"}:
            .:
            f:apiVersion:
            f:blockOwnerDeletion:
            f:controller:
            f:kind:
            f:name:
            f:uid:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:authorizationURL:
        f:dnsName:
        f:issuerRef:
          .:
          f:group:
          f:kind:
          f:name:
        f:key:
        f:solver:
          .:
          f:http01:
            .:
            f:ingress:
              .:
              f:class:
        f:token:
        f:type:
        f:url:
        f:wildcard:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:presented:
        f:processing:
    Manager:    controller
    Operation:  Update
    Time:       2021-11-24T14:39:58Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Order
    Name:                  citizen-capital-preprod-tls-7dnxx-3938188414
    UID:                   ee84badd-8772-4714-bd39-f869da6badf5
  Resource Version:        16344990987
  UID:                     cedd6cb8-2cd5-41f1-91c6-90c97241e051
Spec:
  Authorization URL:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/52313206250
  Dns Name:           citizen-capital.preprod.kmp.agency
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:  cert-manager.io
    Kind:   ClusterIssuer
    Name:   letsencrypt-prod
  Key:      VHmIjwoNb8u65ji1vf9MJ8S20RROfEgsaorfFD0tSMI.W7XMaaaYwtVRQ97c6c1PC2d4h_11U1k55BYGYTLWJ-o
  Solver:
    http01:
      Ingress:
        Class:  nginx
  Token:        VHmIjwoNb8u65ji1vf9MJ8S20RROfEgsaorfFD0tSMI
  Type:         HTTP-01
  URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/52313206250/4sKP4A
  Wildcard:     false
Events:         <none>
```

Logs of cert-manager

```
[cert-manager-78866786cb-wg7j9 cert-manager]  I1124 14:39:54.830516       1 conditions.go:182] Setting lastTransitionTime for Certificate "citizen-capital-preprod-tls" condition "Ready" to 2021-11-24 14:39:54.830506924 +0000 UTC m=+1153.448694540
[cert-manager-78866786cb-wg7j9 cert-manager]  I1124 14:39:54.830840       1 trigger_controller.go:189] cert-manager/controller/certificates-trigger "msg"="Certificate must be re-issued" "key"="citizen-capital/citizen-capital-preprod-tls" "message"="Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist" "reason"="DoesNotExist"
[cert-manager-78866786cb-wg7j9 cert-manager]  I1124 14:39:54.831259       1 conditions.go:182] Setting lastTransitionTime for Certificate "citizen-capital-preprod-tls" condition "Issuing" to 2021-11-24 14:39:54.831253542 +0000 UTC m=+1153.449441192
[cert-manager-78866786cb-wg7j9 cert-manager]  E1124 14:39:54.907949       1 controller.go:158] cert-manager/controller/certificates-trigger "msg"="re-queuing item due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificates.cert-manager.io \"citizen-capital-preprod-tls\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="citizen-capital/citizen-capital-preprod-tls" 
[cert-manager-78866786cb-wg7j9 cert-manager]  I1124 14:39:54.908354       1 trigger_controller.go:189] cert-manager/controller/certificates-trigger "msg"="Certificate must be re-issued" "key"="citizen-capital/citizen-capital-preprod-tls" "message"="Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist" "reason"="DoesNotExist"
[cert-manager-78866786cb-wg7j9 cert-manager]  I1124 14:39:54.908448       1 conditions.go:182] Setting lastTransitionTime for Certificate "citizen-capital-preprod-tls" condition "Issuing" to 2021-11-24 14:39:54.908443178 +0000 UTC m=+1153.526630793
[cert-manager-78866786cb-wg7j9 cert-manager]  I1124 14:39:55.399333       1 conditions.go:242] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "citizen-capital-preprod-tls-7dnxx" condition "Approved" to 2021-11-24 14:39:55.399324722 +0000 UTC m=+1154.017512332
[cert-manager-78866786cb-wg7j9 cert-manager]  I1124 14:39:55.438715       1 conditions.go:242] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "citizen-capital-preprod-tls-7dnxx" condition "Ready" to 2021-11-24 14:39:55.438707025 +0000 UTC m=+1154.056894632
[cert-manager-78866786cb-wg7j9 cert-manager]  I1124 14:39:55.469496       1 conditions.go:242] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "citizen-capital-preprod-tls-7dnxx" condition "Ready" to 2021-11-24 14:39:55.469486006 +0000 UTC m=+1154.087673623
[cert-manager-78866786cb-wg7j9 cert-manager]  E1124 14:39:55.483167       1 controller.go:158] cert-manager/controller/certificaterequests-issuer-acme "msg"="re-queuing item due to error processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificaterequests.cert-manager.io \"citizen-capital-preprod-tls-7dnxx\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="citizen-capital/citizen-capital-preprod-tls-7dnxx"
```

As you can see, the challenge has been successfully created but no event is triggered.
And there is no temporary ingress created for the challenge.

Comment: Take a look at the last line - "Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificate requests.cert-manager.io...". According to [this GitHub isssue](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/3501) it may be related to that you reinstalled CM installation, could you follow answers from this topic to clean your CM stuff and check it? It it won't help, could you please share steps / instructions that you used to setup it, so it will be [possible to reproduce it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Could you share information how did you setup your Kubernetes cluster and which version of the Kubernetes are you using?